# Creando eventos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Con el siguiente código estoy intentando crear varios eventos. En el primer evento me sale primero la alerta que la página en html y no sé por qué. Con los otros eventos entiendo que los debo hacer con la funció focus() pero estoy un poco perdido.
A ver si me pueden ayudar un poco a resolver estos problemas.

```js
    // Botón guardar
    document.getElementById("Guardar").addEventListener("click", function(){
      alert("Guardado");
    });
    
    // Foco input color cambia
    document.getElementById("Nombre").addEventListener("focus", function(){
      this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    });
    document.getElementById("Nombre").addEventListener("blur", function(){
      this.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });
    
    // Input vocal o consonante color cambia
    document.getElementById("Letra").addEventListener("input", function(){
      let valor = this.value;
      if (valor.length === 1) {
        let vocales = "aeiouAEIOU";
        if (vocales.includes(valor)) {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        } else {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
      <h1>Eventos</h1>
    
    <p>Haz que cuando se haga click sobre el botón “Guardar”, salte un alert con un mensaje de guardado.</p>
    
    <button id="Guardar">Guardar</button>
    
    
    <br>
    
    <br>
    
    <p>Cuando hagamos foco sobre este input se pondrá de color amarillo y cuando se lo quitemos cambiará de color</p>
    
    <label>Nombre</label>
    
    <input type="text" id="Nombre"/>
    
    <br>
    
    <br>
    
    <p>Dependiendo si escribamos una vocal o una consonante el contenido del input aparecerá de distinto color</p>
    
    <label>Escribe una letra</label>
    
    <input type="text" id="Letra"/>
```

Al ejecutar el script da un error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at index.js:2:35
Por alguna razón desconocida, desde Visual Studio Code no se ejecuta el script.

Comment: Cual seria el problema?

Comment: En el primer paso me sale antes la alerta que la página html. Y en los dos enunciados posteriores no sé cómo formular las funciones